# Proper escaping of quotes and parens when using expect, ssh, ant and mysqldump

Tags: shell, ant, ssh, mysql, expect

We currently have a working ant script that will use mysqldump to dump a database on a remote server to a file on that remote server.  We use ant's exec task to run an expect script to ssh to the remote machine and run the mysqldump command.  I'm trying to update the command to restrict the dump to only include data that is less than 3 months old.  I'm running into annoying escaping issues with quotes and parens.

Here is the command line I'm trying to get working:

```
expect -f ssh-pass.exp <SERVER_PASSWD> ssh <USER>@<IP_ADDRESS> \"mysqldump -h localhost -u user --password=passwd staging --where=\"createTimeFi > now() - interval 3 month\" --ignore-table=staging.JMS_MESSAGES --ignore-table=staging.JMS_ROLES --ignore-table=staging.JMS_SUBSCRIPTIONS --ignore-table=staging.JMS_TRANSACTIONS --ignore-table=staging.JMS_USERS --ignore-table=staging.TIMERS > dump.sql\"
```

Here is the expect script:

```
set password [lrange $argv 0 0]
set command [lrange $argv 1 1]
set arg1 [lrange $argv 2 2]
set arg2 [lrange $argv 3 end]
puts "command: $command"
puts "arg1: $arg1"
puts "arg2: $arg2"
set timeout -1
spawn $command $arg1 "$arg2"
match_max 100000
expect "*?assword:*"
puts "\rsending password..."
send -- "$password\r"
puts "\r**************** Running remote command, wait... ******************"
expect eof
```

I've tried various combinations of escaping quotes around the ssh command and the where argument to mysqldump with no success.  Sometimes expect will complain that "interval" is an unknown command.  Sometimes on my local machine the command will create files called "now" or "dump.sql" which seem to indicate that my local shell is eating the quotes and doing redirects where it shouldn't or it will complain about invalid tokens (i.e. the parens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an Expect issue. It's only related to shell quoting.

You need to pass that long mysqldump command and its arguments as a single "word", so you can't escape the outer quotes.  And you can use single quotes as the outer quotes so you don't have to escape the inner double quotes.

`expect -f ssh-pass.exp <SERVER_PASSWD> ssh <USER>@<IP_ADDRESS> 'mysqldump -h localhost -u user --password=passwd staging --where="createTimeFi > now() - interval 3 month" --ignore-table=staging.JMS_MESSAGES --ignore-table=staging.JMS_ROLES --ignore-table=staging.JMS_SUBSCRIPTIONS --ignore-table=staging.JMS_TRANSACTIONS --ignore-table=staging.JMS_USERS --ignore-table=staging.TIMERS > dump.sql'`

====

update: Some notes about your Tcl (expect)

1. use `[lindex $argv 0]` instead of `[lrange $argv 0 0]`
2. the mysqlcommand was sent with braces because you create it as a list (`[lrange $argv 3 end]`) but it should be a single string. Now that you're using proper shell quoting, `[lindex $argv 3]` will suffice and solve this issue too. If you don't pass it to expect as one argument, then `set remote_command [join [lrange $argv 3 end]]` and then `spawn $command $arg1 $arg2`

Comment: Thanks.  This got me close.  I had to switch to using bash instead of zsh and I did have to tweak my expect script, as the mysqldump command was getting sent with curly braces around it.

Comment: Note that inside your quotes, you can also add newlines and tab indentation to make it readable.  If you really go nuts, you could have a 200-line script inside one massive set of quotation marks (not that that is always a good idea).

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the tip on using lindex - I was getting braces around some of my input too and that solved it +1